# Adding a > to markup using regex

Tags: regex

really easy question

```
$config['markup'][] = array("/\[gt\](.+?)\[\/gt\]/s", "<span class=\"quote\">\$1</span>");
```

With that current code, [gt]foobar[/gt] will output foobar and apply the span and it works fine, however, I was wondering if

```
$config['markup'][] = array("/\[gt\](.+?)\[\/gt\]/s", "<span class=\"quote\">\>\$1</span>");
```

would make it so that [gt]foobar[/gt] would output >foobar

if that isn't the case, how could I achieve the desired output?

Comment: The best way to test this would be to try it. You don't need to escape the `>` and the `$` with a slash, but you do need to turn the angled bracket into an HTML character entity: `&gt;`.

Comment: You don't need to escape `]` too

Comment: I am not sure what regex implementation you are using, but you SHOULD escape `>`, `<`, `[`, `]`, and `$`.  These characters can have special meaning.

Comment: @willOEM The `<`, `>`, and `$` aren't in the pattern though, they're in the replacement string - they probably _shouldn't_ be escaped there.